# Control child component - Angular 2

Tags: angular, components, parent-child

I need to create a component that controls other components that are your children, but without knowing which component Something like this:

```
<grid-component [model]="User">
    <user-form-component> </user-form-component>
</grid-component>

<grid-component [model]="Post">
```

The treatments for both components should be equivalent:
- List table according to the model parameter;
- Mount button that opens modal with the child component.

I tried in several ways:

`@ViewChild (UserFormComponent) comp: UserFormComponent` Can not be fixed comp type, since for each screen it would have a different component;

`<ng-content> </ng-content>` I can not control and send variables to content in order to control a modal or the item being edited;

Comment: each component has Inputs and Outputs, through which they can communicate

Comment: You'd have to look into dynamic component, from there you can load the component based on your input. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader